# Using YouTube Iframe API inside of jquery plugin to get state

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, youtube

I'm stuck at using the Youtube API inside of my jquery plugin function. It doesn't work at all. I've tryed the new YT.player() method but it outputs YT as nonexistent.

```
$videos = $('.video iframe');

$videos.each(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    //use id to attach video state listener
});
```

How can I attach a state listener to each of the videos in order to get the state of the video?

Thank you very much, I'd really appreciate your help!

Comment: Do you have global function `onYouTubePlayerReady`? Make sure you instantiate the `YT.Player()` within this function.

Answer (score 0):

```
   var player = new YT.player()

    (function($, player) {

       $.fn.testPlugin= function(options) {

            console.log(player);

       }
    }) (jQuery,player);
```

try it.